# How to include special characters in A-frame web VR (čšž...)

Tags: special-characters, aframe

I want to create a website readable not only in english but i have problems with special characters. I've tried ascii html. 
Any idea?

Comment: You mean special characters in the `<a-text>` component ?

Comment: yes and the a-plane

Answer (score 4):

If You have troble with the text component there are three ways I can think of:

1) The proper way: find or generate a font from a fontset containing those characters. The docs describe how to use [custom fonts](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/text.html#custom-fonts):

```
 <a-entity text="text: Hello World; font: ../fonts/CustomFnt.fnt;    
 fontImage: ../fonts/CustomFnt.png"></a-entity>
```

But you need to have a font file + a .png grid with the font images.
The docs provide a link to a [tool](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) for generating fonts, as well as a [tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts).

2) check out Don McCurdy's custom font [generator](https://msdf-bmfont.donmccurdy.com/) !

3) The workaround: You could make a transparent image containing Your text and put it on an `<a-plane>`, like I did [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lively-index?path=index.html:1:0).

Comment: 2 doesn't work  becouse i've tried it in a-plane and a-text

Comment: how can you use src -explain how did u do it

Comment: @Tim. `src` is an attribute which points to the texture. In this case, i made a picture with a transparent background using GIMP. You can see it in the glitch [assets](https://cdn.glitch.com/ca981600-15da-43b1-bd8d-088b18599bc1%2Ftext.png?1520799020242).

Comment: I was ordered not to use images

Comment: ok then, check out the [hiero tool](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) as well as the [instruction](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts#generating-the-font). You need to generate the .fnt file with the .png like i described.