# Display UTF8 text with accents in AFRAME like á í ñ

Tags: aframe

When I try to use some spanish words in my interface of AFRAME project all characters with accent disapear:

```
<a-text  id="menu-desc" value="Menú" 
position="-0.18 -0.06 0.1" 
height="1" width="1" 
align="left" anchor="left"
baseline="bottom" ></a-text>
```

just display "Men" instead "Menú".

In the html page I try to add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

with no effect. ¿how to display correctly that kind of characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include special characters in A-frame web VR (čšž...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223807/how-to-include-special-characters-in-a-frame-web-vr-%c4%8d%c5%a1%c5%be)

Answer (score 2):

I can't mark this as a duplicate, so i'll paste my anwser from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223807/how-to-include-special-characters-in-a-frame-web-vr-%C4%8D%C5%A1%C5%BE):

---

It's not as simple as adding the meta type, since `a-text` is not just displaying characters, it's rendering them in the engine.

So there are three ways I can think of:

1) The proper way: find or generate a font from a fontset containing those characters. The docs describe how to use [custom fonts](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/text.html#custom-fonts):

```
 <a-entity text="text: Hello World; font: ../fonts/CustomFnt.fnt;    
 fontImage: ../fonts/CustomFnt.png"></a-entity>
```

But you need to have a font file + a .png grid with the font images.
The docs provide a link to a [tool](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) for generating fonts, as well as a [tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts).

2) check out Don McCurdy's custom font [generator](https://msdf-bmfont.donmccurdy.com/) !

3) The workaround: You could make a transparent image containing Your text and put it on an `<a-plane>`, like I did [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lively-index?path=index.html:1:0).

Comment: Thanks Piotr, sorry for the duplicate question, I didn't find it.

Comment: @Pierre no problem, if this solves Your problem, mark the anwser and i'll mark the other one as a duplicate :p